# Quantile Boxplots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have summary statistics for 30 observations, namely: minimum value, maximum value, mean/median, 25th percentile and 75th percentile. If I had the underlying data for these numbers, I could simply do a boxplot in ggplot2 and all of these numbers would drop out, but I only have the summary statistics. Is there a way of doing a boxplot in ggplot just using these numbers? Thanks.

Comment: Have you looked in the help file of `geom_boxplot()` - there is an example how to do that!

Comment: @Didzis Elferts thanks for that, should have gone there first. When you say help file, that's the ggplot2.pdf reference manual I take it? New to all this.

Comment: No, type `help(geom_boxplot())` in your R session or go to website mentioned in answer of @Titolondon

Comment: @Titolondon, thanks appreciated.

Comment: @Didzis Elferts, when I type help(geom_boxplot()) in RStudio I receive the message: Error in help(geom_boxplot()) : 
  'topic' should be a name, length-one character vector or reserved word. Update: ??geom_boxplot() gets me there.

Answer (score 5):

It is explained in the help page of `geom_boxplot` - see the last example.
You could see it in the [ggplot2 docs site](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_boxplot.html)

**The following example is extracted from the help page**

```
# It's possible to draw a boxplot with your own computations if you
# use stat = "identity":
y <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(
  x = 1,
  y0 = min(y),
  y25 = quantile(y, 0.25),
  y50 = median(y),
  y75 = quantile(y, 0.75),
  y100 = max(y)
)
ggplot(df, aes(x)) +
  geom_boxplot(
   aes(ymin = y0, lower = y25, middle = y50, upper = y75, ymax = y100),
   stat = "identity"
 )
```

[image: boxplot]